# Webclient and Javascript must be enabled

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone, webclient

Here's my issue, I was using a webclient to download the html code of the following page http://audiko.net/search?q=lana+del+rey&search-options=audiko-search-options and do some parsing after download.

Now when I try to download through webclient all I get is a " Javascipt must be enabled" message.

And I can't find a way to bypass this thing.

Any ideas?

Platform: Windows Phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done in order to solve the problem was the following

Added a hidden web browser to my .xaml page, through the C# code I used the navigate method of the webbrowser, subscribed to the LoadCompleted event and the called the SaveToString() method of the webbrowser and voila.